# How do I get this program to print out the state with the highest score and states with score > 500?

Tags: python

I'm so close.  I'm able to print out the max score but cannot get it to print out the state name.  I'm also unsure how to get it to print out the state names with scores greater than 500.  Here is some sample data.  It is from a text file as you see in my code below:

```
New_York        497 510 
Connecticut     515 515 
Massachusetts   518 523 
New_Jersey      501 514 
New_Hampshire   522 521 
D.C.            489 476
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
StateFile = open ('state_satscores_2004.txt', 'r')

count = 0

ScoreList = [ ]

for line in StateFile:

    # increment adds one to the count variable

    count += 1

    # strip the newline at the end of the line (and other white space from ends)

    textline = line.strip()

    # split the line on whitespace

    items = textline.split()

    # add the list of items to the ScoreList

    ScoreList.append(items)
# print the number of states with scores that were read

print('The number of SAT Scores for states is:', count)

score = []
for line in ScoreList:
    score.append(int(line[1]))

print(max(score))

print(score>500)



for line in score:
    print('The scores are', score)


# print the lines from the list

for line in ScoreList:
    print ('The scores for ', line)



StateFile.close()
```

Comment: first edit question, select code and press button `{}` on toolbar to correctly format code.

Comment: do you know `if/else/elsif` ?

Comment: Do I know of it...yes.  However, I'm not very good at it.  R is my language and Python has been very hard for me to understand up to this point.

Comment: On the max score, I can get it to print the score, but not the state yet.  On the scores > 500 I cannot figure out how to make it work.  I've tried > sign outside the parenthesis also.  Still doesn't work.

Comment: don't create list `score` but use `ScoreList` - `if line[1] > 500: print( line[0] )`

Comment: if you will keep elements as `(score, state)` then you can sort it - `ScoreList = sorted(ScoreList)` and it will sort it first by score (and element with the same score it will sort by state) and finally last element will have the biggest score.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code inside your `print()` call in the last line, `score>500`, is actually a *condition* that evaluates to either `True` or `False`. It's not actually an instruction to the `print()` function to print every element greater than `500`.

That may be confusing to hear, since `max(score)` does sort of behave in that way - but `max(score)` is another method call that actually returns a value (which is then printed).

The simplest version of what you're looking for is a for loop - iterating over `ScoreList` and printing out each value that is greater than 500.

Here's an example.

```
...
print(max(score))

for line in ScoreList:
    if line[1] > 500 or line[2] > 500: # if either score is > 500, then...
        print(line[0]) # ...print the name of the state.
```

You could do this in your existing for loop on `ScoreList` of course; you don't need to loop over it a second time, but I wanted to show this loop by itself.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining that and doing it in a nice manner.  Yes, that's what was throwing me is that the max works easily so it seemed like it should work.  Thank you for showing me why it doesn't work.  Not everyone is very kind to those of us that are just trying to learn.  So I really appreciate it.

Comment: We all have to start somewhere :) Welcome to programming!

Comment: I wish everyone had your attitude.  I get what I was doing wrong now.  This all makes sense.  You just got me through a serious block I was having.  Thank you again!